# ArcMap depicts reduced selection of annotations

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, annotation

I have a shapefile with labels for parcels on my map. I want to convert these into annotations at a scale of 1:1000. Whenever I convert the labels into annotations not all of them are converted, there are missing some annotations.[image: map with labels from a shapefile]

[image: map with annotations]

Is there a setting that allows to convert all my labels into an annotation?
This is the attribute table of the shapefile
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If certain labels are turned off (e.g. in a congested area) when you convert the labels to annotation, the annotation features will exist as unplaced annotation. They should still exist in the attribute table with a Status of -1 (unplaced), as long as you have checked Convert unplaced labels to unplaced annotation in the Convert Labels to Annotation dialogue.

You may want to see if there's any annotation features showing a value of -1, and potentially field calculating the field to 0 to turn them all on.

To view unplaced labels before the conversion, there is a View Unplaced Labels button in the Labeling Toolbar.